# Regex vs. string:find() for simple word boundary

Tags: c++, regex, performance, search

Say I only need to find out whether a line read from a file contains a word from a **finite** set of words.

One way of doing this is to use a [regex](http://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html) like this:

```
.*\y(good|better|best)\y.*
```

Another way of accomplishing this is using a **pseudo** code like this:

```
 if ( (readLine.find("good")   != string::npos) ||
      (readLine.find("better") != string::npos) ||
      (readLine.find("best")   != string::npos) )
 {
   // line contains a word from a finite set of words.
 }
```

Which way will have better performance? (i.e. speed and CPU utilization)

Comment: Regex all the way for me - Everyone knows it and it is quick and easy to use.

Comment: @Chuck *Everyone* knows regex? How untrue that is. :)

Comment: This seems rather easy to measure and test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regexp will perform better, but get rid of those '.*' parts. They complicate the code and don't serve any purpose. A regexp like this:

```
\y(good|better|best)\y
```

will search through the string in a single pass. The algorithm it builds from this regexp will look first for \y, then character 1 (g|b), then character 2 (g => go or b => be), character 3 (go => goo or be => bes|bet), character 4 (go => good or bes => best or bet => bett), etc. Without building your own state machine, this is as fast as it gets.

Comment: Wow! All answers I received so far were great, but this one is the best IMHO since it also explains why and how the regex engine works in a nutshell. I will have to accept this answer (sorry, I don't have enough point to give upvotes, otherwise I would have given upvotes to everyone who answered my question).

Comment: If you use a compiling regex engine like Google's RE2, search speed will likely be the same with and without `.*`.

Answer (score 4):

You won't know which is faster until you've measured, but the issues at stake are:

1. The regex implementation, esp. whether it needs to precompile (like Google RE2, POSIX regexes).
2. The implementation of `string::find`.
3. The length of the string you're searching in.
4. How many strings you're searching in.

My bets are on the regex, but again: you've got to measure to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously not the second one (using 'find'), since you're running three comparisons (need to traverse the string at least 3 times) instead of one hopefully smart one. If the regex engine works at all like it should (and I suppose it does) then it will probably be at least three times faster.

Comment: You can't really say this without measuring. If the lines are short enough, they might fit in a single line of CPU cache and `find` may be pretty fast.

Comment: larsmans - well, yes, in theory the finds could somehow be just as fast or even faster. since the question is performance, the "big difference" case would be a very long string.

Comment: not necessarily; the "big difference" case could be many small lines taken out of a big chunk of text already in memory.

Comment: Seth: not neccesarily, but my gut feeling is that even in the case of many small lines already in the cpu's cache, it will be faster to run the compiled regex on them than multiple finds